# Autocomplete en input solo muestra 8 resultados cuando hay mas en Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Buen dia,

tengo un autocomplete que me trae coincidencias de unos productos de una base de datos Mysql, por ejemplo, productos que tengan la palabra "buje" hay 11, el php efectivamente me devuelve los 11 existentes, aqui la respuesta que viene del PHP mediante AJAX

```
["BUJE PVC PRESION ROSCADO 3/4" X 1/2" PAVCO", "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1.1/2" X 1" PAVCO",…]
0: "BUJE PVC PRESION ROSCADO 3/4" X 1/2" PAVCO"
1: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1.1/2" X 1" PAVCO"
2: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1.1/2" X 1/2" PAVCO"
3: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1.1/2" X 3/4" PAVCO"
4: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1" X 1/2" PAVCO"
5: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 1" X 3/4" PAVCO"
6: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 2" X 1.1/2" PAVCO"
7: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 2" X 1" PAVCO"
8: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 2" X 1/2" PAVCO"
9: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 2" X 3/4" PAVCO"
10: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 3" X 2" PAVCO"
11: "BUJE PVC PRESION SOLDAR 3/4" X 1/2" PAVCO"
```

pero en el autocomplete siempre me muestra los primeros ocho cuando no he limitado por ningun lado eso

[image: LO QUE MUESTRA EL AUTOCOMPLETE]

pasa lo mismo para cualquier producto, siempre muestra 8 resultados cuando en realidad puede que hayan 50

aqui el js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#input_descripcion_buscar_producto_por_nombre').typeahead(
  {
    source: function (query, result)
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: "../PHP/autocompletar_info_producto_existente.php",
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
         $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("buscando..");
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
          if(data=="producto no encontrado")
          {
            $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("Producto no existe");
            return;
          }
          result($.map(data, function (item)
          {
            $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("");
            return item;
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Aqui el PHP

```
    <?php
    require('conectar.php');
    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
     $query = "SELECT distinct descripcion FROM productos WHERE descripcion 
     LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' ORDER BY descripcion ASC";
     $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     //armo un array con los resultados
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $output[] = $row["descripcion"];
     }
    }
    else
    {
       $output='producto no encontrado';
    }
    mysqli_close ($conexion);
    echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

Aqui el Css

```
.typeahead
{
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:8px 12px;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 290px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
.tt-menu
{
    width:300px;
}
ul.typeahead
{   
  margin:0px;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li a 
{
  padding: 10px !important;
  width:500px;
  border-bottom:#CCC 1px solid;
  color:#000000;
}
ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li:last-child a
{
  width:500px;
  border-bottom:0px !important;
}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #9bcbeb;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Exactamente que `plugin` estas usando? Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega esta info.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la propiedad maxLength a false

```
maxLength: false
```

Resultando asi tu archivo JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('#input_descripcion_buscar_producto_por_nombre').typeahead(
        {
        maxLength: false,
        source: function (query, result)
        {
          $.ajax({
            url: "../PHP/autocompletar_info_producto_existente.php",
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function()
            {
             $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("buscando..");
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
              if(data=="producto no encontrado")
              {
                $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("Producto no existe");
                return;
              }
              result($.map(data, function (item)
              {
                $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("");
                return item;
              }));
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Lo he hecho pero sigo viendo los mismos 8 resultados

Comment: Puedes intentar en la funcion verificar si llegan todos los resultados, si llegan todos quiza si se muestran pero tu CSS solo esta puesto en ciertos px's y esos pixeles no muestran mas que los 8

result($.map(data, function (item)
          {
            $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("");
            return item;
          }));

Comment: He hecho un console.log(data) y efectivamente veo los 11 resultados, en cuanto al css, en donde dices que debo aumentarle de tantas clases que se usan ahi?

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer mas que nada es usar las herramientas de desarrollador de google chrome para ver si el elemento html tiene los 11 resultados, si tiene los 11 resultados si es el CSS, intenta haciendo mas grande el .typehead.

Answer (score 0):

arriba del parametro *source* del objeto que pasas a typeahead puedes agregar `limit: Infinity,`

Comment: Lo he hecho y nada, hice un console.log(data) y efectivamente veo en consola los 11 resultados pero sigue mostrandome solo 8

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución, simplemenmte debia agregar la propiedad items: 9999 para que me deje mostrar mas de 8 elementos